# How can I be dm a private user if I have a custom prefix

Tags: discord.js

I have a custom prefix command that works great as desired, only when I am a user dm the bot always crashes and I just don't know why the only error that comes up is **'id of undefined'**. Here is the part of the code where I suspect it won't work. I hope someone can help me with my problem.

I fixed the bug That was the mistake: **id of undefined** and that was the solution

```js
if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;
```

```js
let prefixes = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./code/prefix.txt", "utf8"));

if(!prefixes[message.guild.id]) {
  prefixes[message.guild.id] = {
    prefix: botprefix.prefix,
  }
}

let prefix1 = prefixes[message.guild.id].prefix;

if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix1)) return;

const args = message.content.substring(prefix1.length).toLowerCase().split(' ');
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question until you translate your title into English

Comment: Ok I changed the title haha ​​I'm totally new to Stackoverflow :D

Comment: SO is an English only platform.

Comment: Do you still have an idea how I could fix the error that if I do user.send ("Hello for example") the bot does not crash?

Comment: Please log `message`, as the most likely reason for this error is that it's not actually a message instance.

Comment: Sry do you mean that I should user so dm? because that still doesn't work `message.member.user.send`